# Stackapps syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, stackapps

Could we have syntax highlighting on StackApps? It would be useful for the [user scripts](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/user-script) for example. That way it's easier to see what a code exactly does (obviously).

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-js -->` also doesn't work.

Comment: @DannyBeckett indeed, that only works when prettify is enabled.

Comment: Language prettify should be enabled for ***all*** posts at stackapps, regardless of tag.  The tag, and the language hints would decide which syntax to apply -- the same as on other sites.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles that's what I meant :) it's a little weird formulated, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is on now... I almost wonder if it wasn't turned *off* at some point though, so if you find a problem let us know.

Comment: Way to ruin the site...