# Going to any question on the site brings an error page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I hope the staff can see this question, not sure if I will once I post.

[image]

Update: This does not happen on meta, this happens in programmers, and in StackOverflow. Happens in meta-programmers too.

If this helps you, here are the response headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 21:09:39 GMT
Content-Length: 18814
```

Comment: Occurs on [so], [sf] and [su], as well as other SE sites.

Comment: We know; Top Men are working hard to fix it...

Comment: Totally killin my workflow

Comment: I have an answer sitting on CTRL-V... :/

Comment: Seems to occur on every beta site and english

Comment: Methinks re-implementing syntax highlighting killed something. ref: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180343/stackapps-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Thanks, was just about to post this too. Hopefully, the 'Top Men' will post what when wrong - that would be cool to know.

Comment: Crap. Now I have to work.

Comment: Who broke it this time? [balpha](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Shog9 DevOops.

Comment: Might be a server fault.

Comment: @doubleDown: Or a stack overflow.

Comment: if they do not know how to fix it, they should ask at stackoverflow

Comment: @Jason Can't continue work until I post my question and get some advice on how to solve my problem. Guess I'll just slack off and answer some questions on SO. Oh wait.

Comment: @doubleDown maybe a super user can fix it

Comment: @Asad: That kind of recursive thinking will lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: People are missing out on the chance to vote up my answers!!

Comment: SE, Y U No Work?!1??!

Comment: Benjamin's Meta rep just skyrocketed for this post.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I guess we have to ask Ubuntu.

Comment: also, google cache FTW

Comment: Why do I keep hitting CMD-R?

Comment: This is my favourite so far: https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/531539836.jpg

Comment: Drupal Answers affected too

Comment: We're closing the shop over here

Comment: well...I can still review suggested edits!

Comment: @doubleDown maybe it will help if we think different

Comment: Admit it, @Shog - this is just a ruse to promote the new 500 pages. They really *are* cool though.

Comment: https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/365705759.jpg too..

Comment: crap, what am I supposed to do now? MSDN? I might as well just chill until SO comes back online.

Comment: Are there anyone trying to figure out the problem? Seems like a SQL service interrupt for me.

Comment: I can see a lot of projects delayed this week lol

Comment: Amazing... Stack Overflow goes down and programmers world wide take a synchronized break.

Comment: How many of the entries in the exception log are caused by people repeatedly pressing F5 to see all of the random images?

Comment: @Brant wait, they are rotating?

Comment: Seems to work fine now. And @JanDvorak: it's random

Comment: Where will I repwhore now? I am ruined !!! :D

Comment: First Google Reader, now Stack Overflow. It's the end of the Internet! PANIC!

Comment: BACK UP! Back to work!!!

Comment: Way to hit the rep cap in less than 5 minutes. You're still no Skeet though.

Comment: @ColeJohnson For what it's worth I was pretty close to it for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186957/searching-for-finds-all-questions-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: issue has been fixed. we came live :)

Comment: I wonder how much one minute of this costs Stack Exchange, Inc. BUT NO PRESSURE GUYS

Comment: You beat me to a great question badge by a mere few seconds.  Well played.

Comment: awesome comments/second ratio on this one

Comment: So, in the excitement of wondering what was wrong, I completely forgot why I came to stack overflow in the first place...

Comment: Is it normal to be comment-vote-capped on meta?

Comment: @Brant 212,755 exceptions this time.

Comment: It is Solved :D

Comment: Go back to work guys

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This was my fault.

The offending code was:

```
Path.Combine("/Content", Regex.Replace(ContentPath, "https?://sstatic.net/","/"))
```

What *should* have been is

```
Path.Combine("/Content", Regex.Replace(ContentPath, "https?://sstatic.net/",""))
```

This meant that the second result which should be something like `stackoverflow` was coming out at `/stackoverflow`.  When you feed that to `Path.Combine()`, you get `/stackoverflow` and not `/content/stackoverflow`...and that path is very wrong for a load that has to occur when rendering the editor.

If you couldn't tell - this is part of the move to SSL (which is now live in our test environment, stay tuned).

Comment: Way to go, Slash...

Comment: sure... blame it on the RegEx so noone gets it

Comment: @kaᵠ looooooool

Comment: I thought that on Meta, if you do something bad, you get downvoted :)

Comment: @chuex But he *fixed* it too!

Comment: `this is part of the move to SSL` *sweet*.

Comment: You should probably tag the question `status-complete` now..

Comment: Should any of us happen to meet a physicist on an island, we'll refer to this as "The Incident."

Comment: @Seth Or close it, like every other "site down for 10 minutes" post

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern be `"^https?://sstatic.net/"`? Only match the beginning? ;)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Close it as what, now that TL is gone?

Comment: You sure RegEx is `(needed|the best choice)` here?

Comment: @Seth Obsolete; there's a close reason exactly for this. We even [used it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/187075/revisions)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Nope. You used off-topic ;-)

Comment: @zch - nope, a proxy instead of the CDN is also valid in this case.

Comment: @kaᵠ - it's very concise, easy to read, and runs only on startup (very rarely after) so perf isn't even a consideration...have a better idea that's just as simple/clean/short?

Comment: @NickCraver in that case it's perfect, btw I like RegEx

Comment: @NickCraver What about the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class? You can use [Uri.AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx). You can get [`PathAndQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx) If you need a querystring too. So `new Uri(ContentPath).PathAndQuery` , seems cleaner and less susceptible to future problems :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you're making assumptions about the input :) sometimes it's a full URL, sometimes relative...and it still wouldn't help in what actually has to happen here...a replacement :)

Comment: @Nick Does this mean you get [a gold badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71780/#comment173496_71810) :)

Comment: @NickCraver Not trying to be offensive,  but is there any QA/Testing going on before pushing these changes? This is the fourth time in 10 days that something unit testing should have caught made it to production. Seems like if anyone should know development practices, it should be the Stack Overflow crew.

Comment: It wasn't your fault. It was balpha's.

Comment: @ChrisS almost always we test locally, in dev, and on meta before it goes live.  The specific problem here is that local and meta do not use the CDN, and do not exhibit the problem...dev uses *another* CDN, and also doesn't exhibit the problem.