# Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined in IE and Chrome on StackOverflow and other sites (Seasoned Advice) but not meta

Tags: support, stack-overflow

This just started occurring.
GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/all.css?v=f9ba46034a7e  error:10
GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=a1bdd83c9445

**CHROME:**

Failed to load resource https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined

**IE:**

Webpage error details
Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined in IE and Chrome on StackOverflow and other sites (Seasoned Advice) but not meta

Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined

Here is the IE error:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Tue, 2 Jul 2013 21:05:54 UTC

Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined
Line: 20
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined
Line: 25
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined
Line: 31
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined
Line: 2804
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined
Line: 159
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined
Line: 2817
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://stackoverflow.com/

**EDIT UPDATE 7/3/2013 8:50 AM CST**

Still seeing this on SO and DYI.StackExchange.com sites

```
stub.js?v=a1bdd83c9445 cdn.sstatic.net/js GET (failed) Pending stackoverflow.com/:10 Parser 13 B 0 B 213 ms
-
all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow GET (failed) Pending stackoverflow.com/:10 Parser 13 B 0 B 74 ms
```

EDIT July 9 2013: Worth noting that the failed "portions" of the page that do not load are HTTPS vs HTTP on the ones that DO load properly:

```
Request URL:https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=d2c9bad99c24

Request URL:https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=2079d4ae31a4
```

Still seeing this error July 9 2013

Loading properly:

```
Request URL:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

EDIT: also loads OK:

```
Request URL:http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js
Request URL:http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css
```

one "perhaps" relevant link: [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2][1]

EDIT 7/15/2013 - partially working: IE8 working but not Chrome

Open page, bad, open linked file, gets stub.js but not CSS, yet still gives a script error:

```
GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=c33c6176913b  stackoverflow.com/:10
GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=3b6d34119f98  stackoverflow.com/:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:16
(anonymous function) stackoverflow.com/:16
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:23
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:30
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:35
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:3077
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:3090
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:3103
```

in Network tab for stub:

```
Request URL:https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=3b6d34119f98
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Referer:https://stackoverflow.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
v:3b6d34119f98
  [1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2
```

Comment: Probably the same issue as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187075/going-to-any-question-on-the-site-brings-an-error-page

Comment: CDN appears to be down

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss are you still seeing this?

Comment: Seems to have been cleared up on Chrome but not IE8

Comment: Clear of cache etc. did not seem to help on IE

Comment: Dead again as of right now on Chrome also for SO site and Seasoned Advice

Comment: NOW it is back OK once again...IE and Chrome

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss can you send me your ISP info and a traceroute to cdn.sstatic.net to team@stackoverflow.com please?

Comment: On its way...to ya

Comment: Just an FYI, this has settled to a persistent error condition on both IE-8 and Chrome 27 at this point in time.  Pulling the URL of the files to the CDN site and pasting them into the browser gives an error.  Example: `https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js`

Comment: I can also confirm this problem in Chrome 27.0.1453.116.  Everything appears fine in IE10.

Comment: Still broken for me also.

Comment: For anyone else posting these - the network panel saying the request failed isn't useful, we know that pretty easily.  Go **directly to the URL that failed** and paste what the error was there.  Ultimately we're going to need TCP dumps here though to figure out what's wrong with the connection from you to our CDN (*very* likely a proxy)

Comment: but is is ODD that `https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=3b6d34119f98` in the URL properly pulls back the file, just not as a part of the page. But `The webpage at https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=c33c6176913b might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED` is produced from a direct link to the CSS

Comment: I am currently experiencing this. This should be reopened. Edit: Most StackExchange sites are not loading the required css and js, except for Meta. I have been experiencing this intermittently for about 1-2 weeks.