# Wrong certificate being used for error image

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, design, ssl

I just saw a server error message at https://serverfault.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/520272/php-fpm-performing-worse-than-mod-php.

The large image on that page is broken as it's being served from https://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/error-missile-command.jpg but the certificate is valid for `*.stackexchange.com`.

This is possibly related to [Going to any question on the site brings an error page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187075/going-to-any-question-on-the-site-brings-an-error-page).

Comment: Seeing this on the error pages for all the SE sites.

Comment: I'm getting this issue still, after the question error thing has been fixed. Questions load but if I go to an error page direct the image doesn't load

Comment: Chrome gives me a big red screen saying "This is probably not the site you are looking for!"

Comment: Saw this on GD.SE as well. Error Image seemed fine on SO though.

Comment: @ToddersLegrande Once you accept the certificate, then it just keeps on "working."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an issue related to site setting moves around SSL.  We haven't moved the certs into place for `http://sstatic.net` yet, though `http://cdn.sstatic.net` (a cert on the CloudFlare side) runs fine...and that's what this error image should be pulling from.

After the last build, this is resolved.

Comment: Soo.. SSL is now in place?

Comment: @Undo in some places, yes - there are [quite a few items on the checkist](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) yet to go.

Comment: Looks like the [404 image needs the same treatment](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/page-not-found-image-not-found)?